# Best data structure to represent teams in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a Python dictionary that lists the team members for couple of matches

```
match={'match1':[a,b,c,x,y,z],'match2':[a,y,z,k,m,o], 'match3':[c,x,a,k,l,m]}
```

I need to calculate the number of matches played by each team member along with every other team member.

For example, a-c=2, a-o=1

What would be the best data structure to represent this data so that I can calculate the total matches for every team member combination easily?

Comment: A `Counter` of course.

Comment: From the documentation I've seen, `Counter` is useful for counting each element. I want to calculate the number of times every team member has played with every other team member.

Comment: yes, so you need to count tuples. But that being said, it is against SO policies to answer zero-effort questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Each match is a set. You have list of sets and then filter them by your criteria, count the sets.

```
s1 = frozenset(['a','b','c','x','y','z'])
s2 = frozenset(['a','y','z','k','m','o'])
s3 = frozenset(['c','x','a','k','l','m'])

def find_common_matches(first_player, second_player, *sets):
        return sum(1 for x in frozenset(*sets) if first_player in x and second_player in x)

lst = [s1, s2, s3]
count = find_common_matches('a', 'c',lst)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a pandas dataframe for this, not because you *have* to but because it's honestly a great package.

```
import pandas as pd

#Define your columns and row values in a dictionary. Columns = Matches, Rows 
#= Players
matches={'match1':['a','b','c','x','y','z'],
         'match2':['a','y','z','k','m','o'], 
         'match3':['c','x','a','k','l','m']}

#Generate the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(matches)

#Shows you which players played in what match.
player_matches = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)

#Adds a new column which is defined as the total number of matches for each 
#player.
player_matches['total'] = player_matches.sum(axis=1)

#Pairing matches can be done. Here's a generalized method for that
def pairCount(a, b, df):
    pairs = 0
    for col in df.columns.tolist():
        if df.loc[a,col] == 1.0 and df.loc[b,col] == 1.0:
            pairs += 1
    return pairs

#For example, a-c=2, a-o=1
ac = pairCount('a', 'c', player_matches)
print(ac)

ao = pairCount('a', 'o', player_matches)
print(ao)
```

The `pandas` package is great and definitely worth learning and playing around with. Tons more you can do!